# How do I block all traffic except firefox?

Tags: networking, security, apparmor

Lets say for example I want to block all traffic except incoming from nginx, outgoing for firefox and allow out and incoming to some torrent client. Would that be possible? I took a look at apparmor and it doesn't appear to have a global profile but I could be wrong.

Is it possible to block it for all users including root but whitelist SOMEUSERNAME internet access?

Comment: What does "incoming from nginx" mean?

Comment: @muru that probably should be a 'for'. Incoming traffic on whatever ports nginx uses (typically 80 and 443). But don't give nginx the ability to connect to google/updates/whatever because it shouldn't need to (and AFAIK doesn't)

Comment: But what will `nginx` do with that incoming traffic if it can't reply, since it isn't allowed outgoing traffic?

Comment: @muru: Doesn't it mean it can communicate if a connection was incoming but it can't create outgoing connections?

Comment: I'd interpret it differently, but filtering `nginx` is not difficult. It should be running as the `www-data` user, and the ports are all known.

Comment: You can leave the question open. Someone might be able to come up with an AppArmor-based solution (which, I suspect, might be more fine-grained than the iptables one).

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to block it for all users including root but whitelist SOMEUSERNAME internet access?

Can be done with iptables:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner SOMEUSERNAME -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -j REJECT
```

This is not very nuanced. Of course, the root user can go ahead and rewrite the iptables rules to give itself permission.

You can whitelist incoming ports (say SSH, HTTP and HTTPS):

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -j REJECT
```

Application-level filtering isn't possible with `iptables`, but you could run Firefox and the torrent client under separate users and thus filter them in a similar way.

Also see:

- [Block network access of a process?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68956/block-network-access-of-a-process)
- [Is it possible to whitelist a specific program in iptables?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/67351/70524)
- [iptables HOWTO](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo)

Comment: I don't know IP tables well. Is the 2nd line reject all and the first accept all by SOMEUSERNAME? Don't I need an incoming line to ignore ssh and other attempts? I wouldn't need to block two processes communicating through sockets on localhost (ie webserver<->redis) so do I need something like `-i eth0`?

Comment: You're correct in your interpretation. Since you said all traffic, this blocks all outgoing traffic (you cannot filter incoming traffic based on user in iptables). Unix sockets would be untouched by iptables.

Comment: hmmm. I'd love it if you can write out a rule or two that blocks all incoming except a specific port. It wouldn't be hard to find out or choose the incoming port of the applications I'd like to use

Comment: have a look at the update, and also check out https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo